# rails sql does not store value in object

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

for this habtm relation b/w listings and categories, listings has to be filtered through two select box populated from the same category model, displaying listings belonging to either or both of the categories.

sql is returning correct listings when checked in the dbconsole but not in the application.

category controller

```
def index
  @categories = Category.all
end

def show
  @category = Category.find_by_sql ["select place from listings l , categories c, categories_listings cl where c.id = cl.category_id and l.id = cl.listing_id and name in (?,?)" ,  params[:name][:id] , params[:name][:id]]
end
```

category index page

```
<%= form_for :categories, :url => {:action => :show}, :method => "get" do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category %><br />
    <%= collection_select(:name, :id, Category.all, :id, :name) %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category %><br />
    <%= collection_select(:name, :id, Category.all, :id, :name) %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

category show page

```
<ul>
  <% @category.each do |c| %>
    <li><%= c %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

this only shows empty boxes - [ ]

what seems to be the issue.

Comment: could you please provide the output from console where you get `Category.find_by_sql ["select place from listings l...`

Comment: try by putting (), Category.find_by_sql(["select place from listings l , categories c, categories_listings cl where c.id = cl.category_id and l.id = cl.listing_id and name in (?,?)" ,  params[:name][:id] , params[:name][:id]])

Comment: look at this - 

C:\Sites\travel>rails dbconsole
SQLite version 3.7.15.2 2013-01-09 11:53:05
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> select place from categories c , listings l , categories_listings cl where c.id = cl.category_id and l.id = cl.listing_id and name in ('Adventure','Adventure');
mumbai
bangalore
sqlite>

Comment: mumbai and bangalore is the result. now since the parameters passed is the same, still the result is as expected.

Comment: @Thahakp nope still i get empty boxes

Comment: Add gem 'pry-rails` to development group, run `bundle install`, add code `<% binding.pry %>` before `<% @category.each do |c| %>`, restart the server and reload the page. Then open place where server is started - you should see smth like console (I hope it works in Windows) where you can test your environment for example @category

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "name"=>{"id"=>"4"}, "commit"=>"Submit"} - this is what is passed by the form. for two select boxes, should this be correct??

Comment: @gotva can you help me verify if the form is passing the correct id?

Comment: If I understand you correctly I can suggest you to rebuild the form. You have a category which has many listings You can try to build a multi_select_box based on values category.listings. In this way you will get in controller params[:listing_ids] (the name of parameter depends on how you call it on the form). And build sql query based on this value. (but this is another problem)

Comment: @gotva undefined method `pry' for #<Binding:0x40b6df8>

Comment: ok (maybe binding has some problem on Win). Change `binding.pry` on `p @category`, reload the page and find the output in development log.

Comment: @gotva log shows d same output. application requires selection from 2 select box. prior to this, i just tried if it can work using ul list. but it stops short of displaying output using select box.

Comment: well... let's rewrite the sql query in this way `Listing.joins(:categories).where("categories.id IN (?)", params[:name][:id])` (I hope the result of the this query is the same)